# Nested navigator options not working or even showing up

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I want to show a back button in the header of a screen that is nested in 2 navigators.

I will first show you how I am nesting the screen, followed by what I have tried

Main stack navigator:

```
<Provider store = {store}>
        <StatusBar style="light" />
        <NavigationContainer>

      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" 
          component={Login}
          options=  {{
            headerLeft: null,
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: 20,
              color: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#121212'
            }
        }}/>

        <Stack.Screen 
          name="Tabs" 
          component={Tabs} <-------------- The screen is nested in tabs
          options=  {{
              title: " ",
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 24,
                color: '#FFFFFF'
              },
             headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#121212'
            },

          }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>
  </Provider>


      
    );
  } 
}
```

Tab navigator, nested within the stack navigator as "Tabs":

```
//Bottom Tabs
function Tabs() {
  return (

<Tab.Navigator
initialRouteName="Home"
tabBarOptions={{
  activeTintColor:"#FFFFFF",
  inactiveTintColor:"#696969",
  style: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000'
  },
}}>

  <Tab.Screen 
    name="Create" 
    component={createFlowStack} <------------ This stack is where the screen header I want to add a back button to lies
    options={{ 
      tabBarLabel: ' ',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
        <Ionicons name="md-add-circle" size={size} color={color} />
      ),
    }}
    
  />

    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I have deleted the other tabs as they are not relevant to the question. This tab, create, is nesting another stack navigator, createFlowStack:

createFlowStack, which is shown when you click on the bottom tab "create"

```
  <CreateStack.Navigator 
    initialRouteName="Create"
    >

      <CreateStack.Screen 
          name="Create" 
          component={Create} />

      <CreateStack.Screen 
          name="Screenshot" 
          component={Screenshot}
          // options={({ navigation }) => ({
          //   headerRight: () => (
          //     <Button 
          //         onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
          //         title="Info"
          //         color="#fff" />
          //   ),
          // })}
        />
```

As you can see, the options are commented out, but it wouldn't matter any way. I am trying to show a back button in header left of this screen, but nothing I have tried works.

What I have tried:

1. headerBackTitle: "back"
2. headerBackTitle: " "
3. A custom header left button
4. headerRight: " "
5. The custom header right button you see commented out

NOTHING works, nothing shows up, its like one of the navigators that createFlowStack is nested in is overriding everything. Please let me know how to fix this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the expo SDK from 39 to 40 fixed the issue!